# ¿Como obtener el filename por el header Content-Disposition por AJAX GET?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy intentando encontrar como obtener el nombre del archivo, es este caso una imagen donde estoy intentando sacar el filename y eso es a traves de los response headers de mi consulta, les muestro en codigo:

```js
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open("GET", "https://ucarecdn.com/ddd4e519-47da-4e0d-b4ee-1d0f719227b8/"); 
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (this.status === 200) {
          reader=new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend=function(f){
             
            //Donde quiero obtener el Content-Disposition
            xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
            //en la Consola sale:
            //Refused to get unsafe header "content-disposition"
            
            // y con:
            console.log(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
            //solo sale:
            //last-modified: 
            //content-type: 
            //cache-control: 
            
            
            document.querySelector(".image").src =f.target.result;
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
      } else {
         console.error('A error has ocurred:\n' + xhr.statusText);
      }
  }
}
xhr.send();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <img class="image" src="" alt="">
  </body>
</html>
```

También pueden verlo en mi [link de jsfiddle aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/itzangell/w01eg27b/55/)

Comment: podrias revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40940790/5215609

Comment: pregunta para que quiees el nombre? es una imagen tipo blob no contiene un nombre definido solo los datos de la imagen! puedes utilizar `ddd4e519-47da-4e0d-b4ee-1d0f719227b8` como nombre si deseas solo diferenciar aunque esta en hexadecimal

Comment: Porque "/ddd4e519-47da-4e0d-b4ee-1d0f719227b8/" es una ruta y el servidor puede mandar por cabezales el nombre real del archivo, no siempre se va a tener que usar la ruta como nombre de archivo.